# pandoc document conversion failed with error 2

Tags: html, r, rstudio, pandoc

when I knit HTML in R studio, I get this:

> "C:/Users/Susan/ANACON~1/Scripts/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS lesson3_student.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output lesson3_student.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\Susan\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\Susan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaUaaRx\rmarkdown-str3cf45da21737.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" 
>   output file: lesson3_student.knit.md
>
> unrecognized option `--smart'
>   Try pandoc.exe --help for more information.
>   Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 2
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   running command '"C:/Users/Susan/ANACON~1/Scripts/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS lesson3_student.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output lesson3_student.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\Susan\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\Susan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaUaaRx\rmarkdown-str3cf45da21737.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"' had status 2 
>   Execution halted

Can someone give me an idea what went wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Hm, could you include the YAML for your Rmd file?

Comment: I'm guessing the version of `pandoc` being picked up in your case comes without support for the `--smart` flag. Presumedly, you have an Anaconda installation or something similar, and that is providing a version of `pandoc` that doesn't support that flag?

Answer (score 21):

Today I had the same problem.
I fixed it by setting the smart option to `false`, as described [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203856138-Option-to-set-output-for-Knit-button).

```
   output:
     html_document: 
       smart: false
```

It seems that `--smart` is no longer supported in the newest pandoc version (1.19.2.1), even though it should be should be; see [discusion on the RStudio forum](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000885267-Rmarkdown-defaults-fail-because-of-Pandoc)