# Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 2 with pkgdown / rmarkdown

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, pandoc, r-package

I'm trying to build a website with [pkgdown](https://hadley.github.io/pkgdown/index.html) so I ran `pkgdown::build_site()`.

This throws the following error:

> Building article 'index.html'
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 2

There was a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427481/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-2) on SO but the answer didn't solve my issue.

My guess was that the problem was in the header of [my vignette](https://github.com/erzk/PostcodesioR/blob/master/vignettes/Introduction.Rmd) which currently is:

```
output: 
  rmarkdown::html_vignette:
    smart: false
    toc: true
```

I tried changing it to:

```
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
```

as it is used in the pkgdown's [vignette](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadley/pkgdown/master/vignettes/pkgdown.Rmd). When I used that code, I got an error and the vignette did not build.

> --smart/-S has been removed.  Use +smart or -smart extension instead. For example: pandoc -f markdown+smart -t markdown-smart. Try
>   pandoc.exe --help for more information. Error: pandoc document
>   conversion failed with error 2 In addition: Warning message: running
>   command '"C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   Introduction.utf8.md --to html --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output pandoc23e071f76af6.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\E\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html"
>   --highlight-style pygments --css "C:\Users\E\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\templates\html_vignette\resources\vignette.css"
>   --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"'
>   had status 2  Execution halted

I changed the header as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427481/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-2) to:

```
output:
  html_document: 
    smart: false
```

This header knits a vignette but I still get the same pandoc error when using `build_site()`.

Pandoc is version 2.0. `sessionInfo()` returns:

> R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
>
> LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252     LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
>
> attached base packages: 
>   stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   pkgdown_0.1.0.9000 devtools_1.13.2
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  MASS_7.3-47
>   compiler_3.4.1   magrittr_1.5     R6_2.2.2         tools_3.4.1
>   withr_1.0.2      roxygen2_6.0.1    Rcpp_0.12.12     memoise_1.1.0 
>   xml2_1.1.1       stringi_1.1.5    stringr_1.2.0    digest_0.6.12
>   commonmark_1.2   rlang_0.1.1.9000

Any ideas how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

I ran the whole thing on Ubuntu and I managed to make it work (see the [repo](https://github.com/erzk/PostcodesioR)). Still don't know what was causing the issue. Here is the output of `sessionInfo()`:

> R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
>
> locale:
>
> LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 LC_ADDRESS=C
>   LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: pkgdown_0.1.0.9000 devtools_1.13.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  MASS_7.3-45
>   magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.2       tools_3.3.3    withr_2.0.0
>   roxygen2_6.0.1 Rcpp_0.12.12   memoise_1.1.0   xml2_1.1.1
>   stringi_1.1.2  stringr_1.2.0  digest_0.6.12  commonmark_1.2
>   rlang_0.1.1

Comment: Not sure the problem is with your vignette. I think the problem is with your README. Try using `pkgdown::build_home()` to see if you have the same error.

Comment: I do get an error when using `build_home()` but I think it's the same underlying reason for both README and vignette. I built the website on Ubuntu, pulled the repo from GitHub to Windows, then tried to build a website again, but it failed.

Comment: Try adding an h1 header (`# some title`) at the beginning of your README file.

Comment: It still doesn't work. One way or another, it wouldn't explain why I managed to run it on Ubuntu, but not on Windows.

Comment: Linux > Windows is the explanation. Unfortunately, I've no Windows computer at the moment to test your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is raised because the argument `--smart` is being used here: `... running command '"C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc" ...  --smart ... "'`. Because `--smart/-S has been removed` for Pandoc 2.0, that's a problem. So, remove `--smart` from the caller or command-line to fix this.

In Pandoc 2+, usage of smart is the same as for any other extension. To enable it, you append `+smart` to either the `--to` or the `--from` argument it, or possibly to both. And to disable, append `-smart`.

For example:

> --to html+smart

Or maybe:

> --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-smart